# What i do is not a dumb thing to make sidenav mode dynamically switch depending on screen width?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to make sidenav in Angular Material having 2 states, for mobile mode (tablets, phones and small windows) and desktop (typical window size on monitors). Also i want to save in localStorage if user opened sidenav before (using localStorage), so i subscribed to BreakpointObserver and if width is less than 1024px it changes sidenav mode to 'hover' otherwise it looks in localStorage for user option 'sideNav' if it's false it won't open, if it's true it is opened by default. If you resize your window it repeats whole procedure. I'm starting to think that i'm writing something rly dumb from the side of performance and code clearance.

**SidenavService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDrawer, MatDrawerMode } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../local-storage/local-storage.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SideNavService {
  public drawer: MatDrawer;
  hasBackdrop: boolean = null;
  mode: MatDrawerMode = this.breakpointObserver
    .isMatched('(min-width: 1024px)') ? 'side' : 'over';
  isSidenavOpened: boolean = this.mode === 'side' ?
    this.localStorageService.isSidenavOpened.value : false;

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
  ) {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe('(min-width: 1024px)')
      .subscribe(result => {
        const res = result.matches ? 'side' : 'over';
        this.mode = res;
        if (res === 'side') {
          this.isSidenavOpened = this.localStorageService.isSidenavOpened.value;
        } else {
          this.isSidenavOpened = false;
        }
      });
  }

  public toggleSideNav(): void {
    if (this.mode === 'side') {
      this.localStorageService.isSidenavOpened.value =
        !this.localStorageService.isSidenavOpened.value;
    }
    this.drawer.toggle().then();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<span [ngClass]="themeService.selectedTheme">
  <div class="mat-app-background without-header">
    <app-header [title]="title"></app-header>

    <mat-drawer-container class="mat-drawer-container" [hasBackdrop]='sideNavService.hasBackdrop'>
      <mat-drawer #drawer [mode]="sideNavService.mode" [opened]='sideNavService.isSidenavOpened'>
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
      </mat-drawer>

      <mat-drawer-content>
        <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-column
             justify-content-between min-height-100">
          <div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
          <app-footer [title]="title"></app-footer>
        </div>
      </mat-drawer-content>
    </mat-drawer-container>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this using **only** CSS media-queries?

Comment: yes, because i won't be able to set in as dynamic param to switch [mode] for <mat-drawer>